# Troubleshooting Aruba AP 92 without controller

Tags: aruba

I have deployed 11 Aruba AP 92 without controller, selecting the correct boot mode at the beginning of the configuration process. The 11 AP were separately configured with IP address, SSID and channel selection. 
When I connect AP on the LAN, 3 of them are visible trough the lan but are not working on the radio interface, "11gn" led is solid red, SSID not visible and there is no radio signal...
I use to deploy Cisco AP and I am fairly new to Aruba, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you buy the IAP series access points, I'm fairly certain that Aruba access points will not work without a controller. You can get them on the LAN, but I seriously doubt you'll get them capable of handling wireless users.

Comment: And if it matters, the smallest controller required to drive that many AP's is a 650.

Comment: I didn't notice it was IAP... Where can I find the bascis to configure